# Oracle date format error

Tags: oracle, date

I am working on oracle table to pull the data. In one of the query i am using 'where' to filtering between date.

```
To_Date(VDATU,'DD-MON-YYYY') >= '03-Jun-2012'
AND To_Date(VDATU,'dd-mon-yy') <= '04-Sep-2012'
```

I am getting error,

```
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

I tried using ('dd-mm-yy') but still it is giving the same error. what may the problem??

Comment: That error could occur as a result of the `To_Date` calls, or as a result of the implicit conversion of the strings (e.g. `'03-Jun-2012'`) to dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to convert `VDATU` (which is presumably a `VARCHAR2`) into a date.

In one place you have `DD-MON-YYYY` and in the other you have `dd-mon-yy`.

Which one is it?  `VDATU` can not be valid for both.

Comment: yeah it is varchar2. it is in format of '01122011'. what is the correct format to be used for conversion??

Comment: Your example is ambiguous, but either 'ddmmyyyy' (1st December) or 'mmddyyyy' (12th Jan).

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing a `DATE` with a `String`, try instead:

```
To_Date(VDATU,'DD-MON-YYYY') >= To_Date('03-JUN-2012','DD-MON-YYYY')
AND To_Date(VDATU,'dd-mon-yy') <= To_Date('04-SEP-2012','DD-MON-YYYY')
```

In case `VDATU` is already a date, you shouldn't convert it `to_date`, all you have to do is:

```
VDATU >= To_Date('03-JUN-2012','DD-MON-YYYY')
AND VDATU <= To_Date('04-SEP-2012','DD-MON-YYYY')
```